# How to use an Obj-c Library/Custom interface in a Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Trying to understand how I can use this in my swift project. 
https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit

I have copied the classes folder into my project but am not sure how to use the various .h and .m files. How would I go about using these files within my storyboard to use the custom appearances?

Did some searching and wasn't really able to understand the various threads that I found.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried and any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use a bridging header, which is used to expose Objective C code to swift. To do this, make a new header file in your project. Import the header files you would like to use in the new header file like this:

`#import <FlatUIKit/FlatUIKit.h>`

And then, in the build settings of your project, define the Objective-C bridging header to be the header file you just created. Now in any swift files that you would like to use the library in just import the classes like this:

`import FlatUIKit`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that when you first add an Objective-C file to an Xcode project, after adding it, Xcode will prompt you whether you want a bridging header file. If you say yes, Xcode will add a file called `projectname-bridging-header.h` and *setup the build* to incorporate the header in the build process.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a broad question so I'll try to provide some basics and hopefully that helps.

If you are unaware, there is a whole book written by Apple about how to use objective-c with swift.  it's available on iBooks for free [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.1) by Apple Inc](https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l)

Here is the online [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35)

You will need to create an objective-c bridging header and import your code through the header.

Your bridging header would look like this:

```
 #import "XYZCustomCell.h"
 #import "XYZCustomView.h"
 #import "XYZCustomViewController.h"
```

If they don't have any modules then you can use them in your swift code and it should see them.  According to Apple:

> Use your custom Objective-C code with the same Swift syntax you use with system classes.

```
 let myCell = XYZCustomCell()
 myCell.subtitle = "A custom cell"
```

If you are importing an Objective-c framework then it should already contain and umbrella header file that takes care of the bridging header stuff for you.  then you just import the framework name into the class that you are planning on using.

```
 import MyCustomFramework
```

Link to the apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID126)